# Implementing cell protection in SAS

Tags: vba, excel, sas, enterprise-guide

I create stored processes for my business partners to execute via SAS E.G. / Add-in for Microsoft Excel (AMO). My business partners generally execute a report I've written in SAS E.G. through Excel where they can view the data on-demand versus waiting for my team to provide it.

This generally works out great, but there is a new requirement I'm trying to satisfy and I'm not entirely sure how to go about resolving it. The management of my business partners has asked that we protect/lock the cells that the data is output to. The output is predictable, so I can use something like R1C1:R70C3 to protect the sheet.

I believe this can be done using DDE, but I'm not entirely sure. The users would be connected to our server at work via their SAS metadata profile which I believe would have an impact. Admittedly, I'm not that familiar with DDE, but basically I'm just trying to lock a row/column combo each time the program is execute.

Here's code that I can use through Excel, I'm just not sure how to integrate this into my SAS program.

```
Sub ProtectActiveSheet()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend DDE - in fact Microsoft just locked it down due to a malware issue and you may need to renable it, if your security team will allow it. I would add in a macro to the work book and use VBA to lock the sheets. You can use the VBA recorder to figure out the code and modify the range. My 2 cents at least.

Comment: I would prefer not to. I have the vba attached above. I'm basically just trying to ensure my business partners cannot alter a spreadsheet after they've executed a stored process.

Comment: There's a file called macrofun.exe that contains the Microsoft command documentation - if it didn't excel in Excel 4.0 though it's not an option today either. The previous links I used don't work and you need a special app to even open the file on Windows 10 or 7. I have it at home and will look up the commands if someone else hasn't already answered your question by then.

Comment: See this thread for similar comments. https://communities.sas.com/t5/Integration-with-Microsoft/DDE-commands-for-Excel/m-p/375867

Comment: I can't imagine that you'd be able to run DDE via the Add-in...

Comment: @Reeza Can you have VBA run the SAS Add-in perhaps?  So instead of using the SAS Add-in directly, they hit a button which runs a VBA macro that calls the add-in and then protects the sheet?

Comment: @joe is correct, DDE wouldn't work, if you were thinking of running it in the add in. This may be worth posting over at communities.sas.com so Chris (EG Developers) can comment on what is and isn't possible.

Comment: @Reeza Actually I think Vince (del Gobbo) is the add-in expert, or at least as far as I can tell (though I'm sure Chris also will know plenty)...

Comment: @Joe, yeah, I was thinking of EG AddIn, not AMO.